# Valid UPDATE, INSERT syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Are these statements valid?

```
UPDATE Table1 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2)  

INSERT INTO Table1 
  (SELECT * FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update statement needs a Set for each field you want to update, so no.
Correct syntax:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.field1=table2.field1, table1.field2=table2.field2 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.keyfield = table2.keyfield
```

Your insert statement will work provided that Table1 and Table2 have the same columns in the same order.

**Edit:**  If you're looking for an example of Update/Insert (Upsert), check out this [blog post](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm) (which works on SQL 2008--not sure about 2005 but doubt it).

Another option is an Update and then an insert.  Example from this [blog post](http://www.kodyaz.com/blogs/software_development_blog/archive/2006/11/05/464.aspx) :

```
UPDATE CustomersA
   SET CustomerName = B.CustomerName
FROM CustomersA A (NoLock)
INNER JOIN CustomersB B (NoLock) ON A.CustomerId = B.CustomerId

And later run the Insert command
INSERT INTO CustomersA (
   CustomerId,
   CustomerName
)

SELECT
   Id,
   Name
FROM CustomersB (NoLock)
WHERE
   Id NOT IN (
      SELECT CustomerId FROM CustomersA (NoLock)
   )
```

Comment: A small caveat is that the Insert will fail if there are any identity fields present.

Comment: You should always specify the columns you want to work with. "Select *" will probably stop working when columns are added, dropped, or reordered.

Comment: There's always MERGE in SQL Server 2008 to perform your UPSERT (UPDATE/INSERT)

Comment: Actually I was trying to do an UPSERT with SQL 2005. There are 2 TSQl additions INTERSECT and EXCEPT. In one of the blogs(http://209.34.241.68/mat_stephen/archive/2005/08/31/410022.aspx) it is said Update Table1 from (Select tab1 Intersect Destination) and Insert into Tab1 from(select tab1 EXCEPT tab2).

Comment: To all, thanks for your inputs.
@Russ: It is SQL 2005, I dont have the Merge functionality.  
  
@C-Pound: I do have the Update and Insert statements that you mentioned. The idea of using the EXCEPT and INTERSECT is to off-set these joins. Also they9MS) claim performance wise these new T-SQL are better than Joins.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
  (SELECT * FROM Table2)
```

That could work - if you're lucky.

I'd recommend using a more strict syntax:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (Field1, Field2, ..., FieldN)
    SELECT Field1, Field2, ..., FieldN
    FROM dbo.Table2
```

I would **always** and **explicitly** specify the schema (dbo) and fields for both my INSERT and my SELECT statements. That way, you can

- eliminate columns that are e.g. computed, IDENTITY and other potential "problem" cases
- your SQL statement won't break when you add another column to either table

Marc